# Rotating elements according to cursor position with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rotation, transition, css-transforms, cursor-position

What I'm trying to make is a jQuery script that rotate the elements inside a div, depending on the cursor position in the browser window.

The proportion is something like:

> maximum_pixels_x-axys : 2° = center_pixels_x-axys : 0°

and the same for y axis.

If the cursor is at the center of the screen, no rotation. If it's somewhere else, it must be rotated from 0° to 2° (or negative values depending on the position of the screen in a relative Cartesian plane). So it's a dynamic rotation with immediate feedback.

Like what you see here: http://css3playground.com/flashlight.php (select from menu "Bevel") but using `transform:rotate` instead of `text-shadow`.

Now I tried that with transit.js, using sin e cos instead of degree ("degree" from 0 to 1 will result). It's not the correct way, I know, but it's the closest method I imagined to obtain a low value for degrees.

```
var max_x = $(window).width();
var max_y = $(window).height();
var center_x = (max_x/2);
var center_y = (max_y/2);

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var mouse_x = e.pageX,
    mouse_y = e.pageY,
    hypotenuse = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((mouse_x-center_x),2)+Math.pow((mouse_y-center_y), 2)),
    cos = (mouse_x-center_x)/hypotenuse,
    sin = (mouse_y-center_y)/hypotenuse;
    $('#div1, #div2').transition({ perspective: '400px', rotateX: sin, rotateY: cos });
});
```

But the results are not what I expected. The divs rotate (in the wrong way, but rotate), but not dynamically.

What do I do?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/lucgenti/LtWtW/11/

Comment: added fiddle link. I don't know why it doesn't work, because in my local folder it works (wrongly as I said).

Comment: For off there is a syntax error on your `.ready`: you need a `);` at the end. Second how are you importing transit.js? The fiddle isn't importing it at all, could you copy your implementation of it to the fiddle?

Comment: If you make the values of `sin` and `cos` more extreme (I did by multiplying them by 30) you can see that it is overloading the browser causing it to freeze

Comment: Fiddle corrected. Transit loaded through "external resources" on left menu. You think it's why transit it's too heavy? Now I try with simple css manipulation.

Comment: [Check out this edit](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/LtWtW/12/) where I set an interval to where it only checks every second. It seems the `.transition` is just overloading the processor

Comment: My browser seems to lag when I put the delay below 500 ms or so

Comment: [Check this out](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/) if you're going to use CSS3 3D animations

Comment: Thanks Zeaklous, now I understand: I'm asking too much from browsers.
Now I need a way to code in a right way the rotation.
Maybe you comprehend what I asked: divs that "look" in the direction of the cursor. The degree would depend on the distance from the center of the window. How can I translate that in a "degree" value? (x and y should be different of course)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some work by both of us, [**here is a new version**](http://jsfiddle.net/LtWtW/34/)
that doesn't use a plugin and is prefix free. **NOTE:** This only works in browsers that support CSS transforms

Here is the jQuery I used to achieve such behavior

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $one = $('#div1'),
        $two = $('#div2'),
        browserPrefix = "",
        usrAg = navigator.userAgent;
    if(usrAg.indexOf("Chrome") > -1 || usrAg.indexOf("Safari") > -1) {
        browserPrefix = "-webkit-";
    } else if (usrAg.indexOf("Opera") > -1) {
        browserPrefix = "-o";
    } else if (usrAg.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
        browserPrefix = "-moz-";
    } else if (usrAg.indexOf("MSIE") > -1) {
        browserPrefix = "-ms-";
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function (event) {
        var cx = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth / 2.0),
            cy = Math.ceil(window.innerHeight / 2.0),
            dx = event.pageX - cx,
            dy = event.pageY - cy,
            tiltx = (dy / cy),
            tilty = - (dx / cx),
            radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(tiltx, 2) + Math.pow(tilty, 2)),
            degree = (radius * 15);

            shadx = degree*tiltx;   /*horizontal shadow*/
            shady = degree*tilty;   /*vertical shadow*/

        $one.css(browserPrefix + 'transform', 'rotate3d(' + tiltx + ', ' + tilty + ', 0, ' + degree + 'deg)');
        $two.css(browserPrefix + 'transform', 'rotate3d(' + tiltx + ', ' + tilty + ', 0, ' + degree + 'deg)');

        if(dx>cx) /*without that horizontal values are reversed*/
            $('#div1, #div2').css('box-shadow', + (-shady) + 'px ' + (-shadx) +'px 5px #3D352A');
        else $('#div1, #div2').css('box-shadow', + shady + 'px ' + (-shadx) +'px 5px #3D352A');
    });
});
```

Comment: @lucgenti It'd be awesome if we could get a kind of shadow effect on them depending on the cursor position... I'll look into it in the coming week or two and update you if I find anything

Comment: I was thinking the same. I have already tried something, but it's not good. I will update here with what I would got.

Comment: @lucgenti I think `box-shadow` would be our best bet (you can see how each variables is affected [here](http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/), we just have to figure out how the first two variables change based on the angle and correlate that with the degree we already have

Comment: @lucgenti Actually, there is a helpful little plugin that you can find [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/LtWtW/20/) that does exactly what we want. All we have to do is download it, edit it to how we want it, and then call it as a resource! It might be interesting to come up with a `box-shadow` method ourselves, but for now I'm happy with the plug in

Comment: Good plugin. But with few more lines to the code you already wrote it's ok. Try. http://jsfiddle.net/lucgenti/LtWtW/26/

Comment: The thing is that those shadows are the opposite of the way I want it, they point to the mouse (kind of) instead of away from it

Comment: Ah sorry. Changing all the sign +/- to shadx and shady would be ok. [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/lucgenti/LtWtW/27/)

Comment: @shubniggurath There is no good way to make it prefix free, but I updated my answer with a more appropriate solution using browser detection (buggy, I'll fix it when I get home in a couple days if I remember)